# Resultado en Query distinto a una View

Tags: mysql, sql

Cuando tiro una query como consulta en el que estoy buscando un porcentaje me arroja un valor.
A la hora de meter esa consulta en una view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW test_view
AS
    SELECT
    COALESCE(
        CONCAT(
            ROUND(
                (
                    SUM(
                        CASE
                            WHEN CONCAT(`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`mes_periodo_carga_c`, '-', `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`anio_periodo_carga_c`) = CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '-', YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
                            THEN `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`porcen_hogar_barrio_popular_c`
                            ELSE 'No hay datos'
                        END
                    )
                    - (
                        SELECT SUM(
                            CASE
                                WHEN CONCAT(`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`mes_periodo_carga_c`, '-', `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`anio_periodo_carga_c`) = CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '-', YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH))
                                THEN `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`porcen_hogar_barrio_popular_c`
                                ELSE 'No hay datos'
                            END
                        )
                    )
                ) / (
                    SELECT COALESCE(
                        IF(
                            IFNULL(`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`porcen_hogar_barrio_popular_c`, 'NONULL') = 'NONULL',
                            'N/A',
                            SUM(
                                CASE
                                    WHEN CONCAT(`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`mes_periodo_carga_c`, '-', `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`anio_periodo_carga_c`) = CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '-', YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
                                    THEN `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`porcen_hogar_barrio_popular_c`
                                    ELSE 'No hay datos'
                                END
                            )
                            - (
                                SELECT SUM(
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN CONCAT(`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`mes_periodo_carga_c`, '-', `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`anio_periodo_carga_c`) = CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '-', YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH))
                                        THEN `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`porcen_hogar_barrio_popular_c`
                                        ELSE 'No hay datos'
                                    END
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        'N/A'
                    )
                )
            * 100,
            1
        ),
        'N/A'
    ) AS `Variación interanual`
FROM
    (`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`
    LEFT JOIN `fort_ciudadania_portenia` ON (`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`id_c` = `fort_ciudadania_portenia`.`id`))
WHERE
    `fort_ciudadania_portenia`.`deleted` = 0
    AND CONCAT(`fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`mes_periodo_carga_c`, '-', `fort_ciudadania_portenia_cstm`.`anio_periodo_carga_c`)
    = CONCAT(MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '-', YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)));
```

me arroja otro resultado, es decir, cuando tiro la query normal me da 0,6% y en la View me da 100%.

¿Qué puede generar esto?

Comment: Sin ver la consulta, es muy difícil saber qué está sucediendo.

Comment: Hola @padaleiana, entiendo, pero poner la consulta no interferiría creo yo en la lógica de porque en una vista se me cambia el valor de la query cuando la tiro como una consulta normal. Mi duda iba por si, quizas (y esto desconocimiento total) existe una configuración de las View que varía de la configuración normal de Mysql

Comment: prefijos, diferentes sources, maybe caches. viendo la query ( o algo similar ) se podría responder mejor ( probaste un drop y recreate view ?)

Comment: btw algunas versiones de mysql te permiten queries que agregan(agrupan?) datos de manera no determinista, again viendo la query se puede inferir

Comment: Agregada. Creo que el problema viene por los valores nulos de la tabla pero me parece raro que en la query esta OK y en la vista no.

Comment: ¿Cómo hacés un sum a una cadena? Atención a los _No hay datos_.

Comment: Buena observación @padaleiana, habian dejado esa cadena dentro del ssuum, pero aún sacandolo y poniendo 0, pasa lo mismo.

Comment: El 'No hay datos' no es problema, ocurre conversión implícita que no afecta la sumatoria; no obstante, tampoco es sano mezclar tipos de datos así. En lugar de usar 'NONULL' o 'N/A' maneja apropiadamente el operador `IS NULL`. Por otro lado, te puedes evitar tantas concatena-conversiones, te dejo [aquí un ejemplo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c8aWmncj3B3L6piVvuunok/0).